# In asynchronous serial transmission start bit is o or 1?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I need to calculate number of characters passed over 1800 baud line and I am confused weather in asynchronous serial transmission start bit is 0 or 1?

Comment: "Which serial protocol"?

Comment: synchronous serial transfer and in second part asynchronous serial transfer with stop bits